# Spring Boot not finding entity in database when packaged as jar

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, maven, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application that connects to a database.

The Model is using the `@Entity` and `@Table(name="")` annotations

When I run my application from within eclipse or from the mvn spring-boot run command the application works fine. This is due to both these scenarios using the unpackaged class files when executing.

If, however, I build using the spring boot plugin and execute the jar using java -jar, then when I access the database I get the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: my.entity.EntityObject
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: my.entity.EntityObject
```

The only source I can assume is the spring boot plugin. Am I missing some configuration?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>my.package.FakeSpringBootAppBooter</mainClass>
    </configuration>
    <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Extra note:

I am using persistence.xml

This is referenced in the bean of `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` I have declared, within a `MergingPersistenceUnitManager`

Comment: is `my.entity.EntityObject` in the jar?

Comment: it is in a jar in the lib folder (as it is from a separate project), within the jar I am running. So myExecJar.jar/lib/extJar.jar/my/entity/EntityObject.class

Comment: @mangusbrother were you able to solve this problem?

Comment: This has been ages and i do not remember what the actual issue was. What i do remember is that Spring boot annotation and xml configuration did not work well together. If you can try to switch to annotation-only or xml-only configuration it might help.